# Chrome not scaling when unplugging monitors properly after update

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, scaling

Im using a thinkpad T460s with a high res display. Before I did some updates, Chrome would scale properly when I unplugged my monitors, now when I unplug them to use my laptop display, everything is still scaled at 1x which is to small for the internal monitor.